# Serving a PDF only after validating token

Tags: php

Is there anyway that I can "block" a user from downloading a PDF file on my server using PHP script? That is, to run a MySQL query when the file is being requested, authenticate the user (through a cookie and MySQL query match) and only if the user is authenticated, to serve him the file.

Thanks,

Joel

Comment: Why can't you simply serve him the location to the file *after* your authentication checks have been met?

Comment: And which part did you have problem with? Authentication? Serving of the file? MySQL query? Cookie management? :)

Comment: @Russell - Because that is not really safe... if people find out about the file's location,  they will be able to go to /file.pdf without being authenticated.

Comment: @Roberto - the question is not about any of those. It is about how to make PHP "if"s condition before serving a PDF file, even when the user enters /file.PDF , and not a PHP file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general technique is to put your downloadables outside the document root, and then allow access via a PHP script, e.g. something like this...

```
 if ($authenticated)
 {
     //name of download - e.g. leaf name of file
     //we strip nasties out of it...
     $dl=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]/i', '', $_GET['download']);

     //build path to files
     $file="/path/to/my/fies/$dl.pdf"; 

     if (file_exists($file))
     {
         //send the file as our response, with headers to make the client
         //interpret this as a saveable download...
         header('Content-type: application/pdf');
         header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
         header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$dl.'.pdf"');
         readfile($file);
     }
     else
     {
         //do a 404 not found
         header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
         echo "Sorry, that file is not available for download";
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Just make sure that there is *no* direct link to the PDF file, and use a PHP script to serve the *file contents* (not its location) after authentication has been performed.

To provide example code, I need to know in the form in which your PDF is stored (is it a file on disk? something else?).

Assuming the PDF is a file on disk:

```
if (!authentication_successful()) {
    // output error message, normal PHP here
}

// Otherwise:
// Tell the browser a PDF is coming
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
// Ask it to present a save dialog, with "downloaded.pdf" as the suggested name
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
// Send back the PDF contents
readfile('original.pdf');
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to accomplish this, some better then others.
Here is just a quick and dirty, off the top of my head method.

```
<?php
//Connect to your database
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('database');

//Query the database
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Auth WHERE Cookie='".mysql_escape_string(@$_COOKIES['auth'])."'");

//Ensure that one and only one instance of the cookie exists in the database
if($results && mysql_num_rows($results) == 1) {
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-length: '.filesize('my.pdf'));
  if(@$_REQUEST['download'] == '1') header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my.pdf'); //This forces the browser to download vs open the file
  readfile('my.pdf');
  exit();
}
else {
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
}
?>
```

If you wish to intercept the url /my.pdf you will need to use your web server's method for URL rewriting.  Like .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 ^/my\.pdf$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```